# How to bypass below script

Tags: javascript, html, css, xss

I am currently attempting to complete the challenges set out in Bodgeit Store. I am stumped on the question:**Conquer AES encryption, and display a popup using: alert("H@cked A3S")**

Below is the code for the encryption:

```js
    loadfile('./js/encryption.js');
    
    var key = "fa84df28-2b79-49";
    
    function validateForm(form){
        var query = document.getElementById('query');
        var q = document.getElementById('q');
        var val = encryptForm(key, form);
        if(val){
            q.value = val;
            query.submit();
        }   
        return false;
    }
    
    function encryptForm(key, form){
        var params = form_to_params(form).replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#39');
        if(params.length > 0)
            return Aes.Ctr.encrypt(params, key, 128);
        return false;
    }
```

This encryption code is founded in the "Advanced Search" section. I have tried to run XSS scripts without the angle brackets to try and bypass the replaces, without luck. Is there any chance I could have assistance on this by any chance. Currently using the below link for Bodgeit Store:

https://bodgeit.herokuapp.com/advanced.jsp

The above JS can be found in the page source.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `.replace(/'/g, '&#39')` looks suspect.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the `encryptForm` function and replace it with a function that returns the unprocessed values, here is an example:

```
function encryptForm(key, form){
    return Aes.Ctr.encrypt(form_to_params(form), key, 128);
}
```

Now you can just set the value of one of the inputs to `<script>alert("H@cked A3S")</script>` and this script element will be added to the result page.

Comment: I know I've been religious about not putting things in global scope when this idea of redefining a global function didn't even occur to me...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol This will be a bit more complex if the function was not in the global context but the main problem here is that user input sanitisation is done on the client side. Currently, I don't think there is any method of doing that securely.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I’ve actually had a look online to see how I could do this before your answer. I unfortunately have not come across any tool that will allow me to modify the source code. Any suggestions as to what I could use?

Comment: @BallsackMuncher You can do this using the browser's **Dev Tools** **Console**. You can find out how to use that on Chrome from [HERE](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the reply again! Seems like I still can't modify the advanced.jsp page in dev tools. There is a util.js script that I can modify, but won't save. I have also tried to edit this in the "Elements" tab with no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @BallsackMuncher I've done this before posting the answer so I'm sure it works. All you have to do is to open the Console, paste the code in my answer there and press **Enter**. Then insert the text in the input and press **Search**. You don't have to modify the file, you just need to modify the code in the runtime environment.

Comment: ahhh right, that worked. Thanks so much for the help :)